# How do I change the color of text in javascript?

Tags: javascript, colors

I wrote a javascript code displaying the date. How would I change the color?

Answer (score 6):

You need to put the text in a separate element, then change the element's `color` CSS property.

This is easiest to do using [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
<span id="date">Please enable JavaScript</span>

$('#date').text(new Date().toString()).css('color', 'red');
```

However, you might want to do it with pure CSS:

(In the `head` tag:)

```
<style type="text/css">
    #date {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Your 'l' at the end should be a semicolon :-)

Answer (score 5):

You could set inline CSS properties of the element where you display the date, by using the [`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style) property:

```
var el = document.getElementById('elementId');
el.innerHTML = date; // set the text
el.style.color = '#ff0000'; // set the text color
```

Or you could apply a CSS class programmatically:

```
el.className = 'yourclass';
```